# should I use aggregation in this case?

Tags: oop, aggregation

In the case that I have a class called Payment that it is a superclass of another class named Card, how can I join that class with another that verifies if the card is valid.
My UML diagram would be like this:

```
Payment<---------Card
```

I have thought of two ways of doing this, but I would like to know which one would be the correct one:

1) model with association to check if the credit card is valid, but not join this to paymentCard:

```
Card_list---1--------------1*---<>Card
```

so within my class Card I call something like:

```
class paymentCard extends Payment
{
     public authorized()        ---abstract method
     {
          if card.verified(card_number) return true;     ---here I call the card class
          else return false;
     }
}
```

2) I have read that I can use aggregation, but I am a little dubious how to use it:

```
class paymentCard extends Payment
{
          Card creditcard                  //aggregation
          public authorized()
          {
               creditcard=new Card(numberCard)
               if creditcard.verified() return true;
               else return false;
          }
 }
```

which one of the two forms is better? For me, the first one looks like a query to a external class that can be also a database, while the second one I am not pretty sure about it

Any comment?

Answer (score 1):

One day you could want to have other payment methods.

IMO, a Payment has a payment_method that can be ByCard, By..., so:

```
class Payment
{
    protected PaymentMethodoption;
}

abstract class PaymentMethod
{
    public abstract bool authorized();
}

class PaymentByCreditCard : PaymentMethod
{
    public override bool authorized() { return card.verified(card_number); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you basically answered your own question. The key-question is: how expensive is creating a credit-card object? Probably is not just pass a number to it as you did on your second example, which means pobably you'll have them stored somewhere else.

Comment: yes @Henrique Barcelos, one should have an array of objects to store the valid credit cards numbers